# How to study the strong and weak convergence of this sequence of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Discuss the strong and weak convergence of the sequence

$$u_n(x)=\sin(x)+\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)$$

in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(0,1)$.

I know that a function $u(x)$ belong to $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ iff the $L^p$ norms of $u(x)$ and $u'(x)$ are finite. In particular we can express the norm in a Sobolev space in this way 
$$||{u}||_{W^{1,p}}=||u||_{L^p}+||u'||_{L^p}$$
where
$$||u||_{L^p}^p=\int_\Omega|u|^pd\omega$$
Since the following integrals are hard to compute i think there is another way to discuss this problem.
$$||u_n||_{L^2}^2=\int_0^1|\sin(x)+\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)|^2dx$$
$$||u'_n||_{L^2}^2=\int_0^1|\cos(x)+2\cos(nx)\sin(nx)|^2dx$$

Maybe could be helpfull knowing that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n(x)=\sin(x)$$
Could someone help me?

Comment: The term $\sin x$ has no role here. Study the sequence $\frac1n \sin^2(nx)$. If you find that it converges then add $\sin x$ to the limit. If it does not converge then $u_n$ does not converge, too.

Comment: Should I only compute the integral of $|\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)|^p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $L^2$ norm of $u_n(x)$ is not so hard to deal with. Remember, we just have to show that it is finite:
\begin{align}
\int_0 ^1\left|\sin(x)+\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)\right|^2\;dx &\leq \int_0^1\left(|\sin(x)| + \frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)\right)^2\;dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sin^2(x)+\frac{2}{n}|\sin^3(x)|+\frac{1}{n^2}\sin^4(x)\;dx \\
&\leq \int_0^1 1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\;dx \\
&=1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2} \\
&< \infty
\end{align}
So $u_n(x)\in L^2((0,1))$. You can do similarly for $u_n'(x)$. Now we look at weak convergence in $L^2$. You made the guess $u_n\rightharpoonup \sin(x)$. We have to show that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 [u_n(x) - u(x)]\phi(x)\;dx=0,\qquad\forall\phi\in L^2$$
We can show this by finding an upper bound on the magnitude of this integral:
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 [u_n(x) - u(x)]\phi(x)\;dx\right| &=\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{n}\sin^2(nx)\phi(x)\;dx\right|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\sin^2(x)\left|\phi(x)\right|\;dx\\
&\leq\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\left|\phi(x)\right|\;dx \\
&= \frac{M}{n}
\end{align}
where $M = \int_0^1|\phi(x)|\;dx <\infty$ because $\phi\in L^2$. Taking the limit, we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\int_0^1 [u_n(x) - u(x)]\phi(x)\;dx\right|= 0$$
For weak convergence of $u_n'$, we make use of the fact that step functions are dense in $L^2$, so that for any $\phi(x)\in L^2$, there exists a sequence of step functions $\phi_\nu(x)$ that converges strongly to $\phi(x)$ in $L^2$. This allows us to just consider the integral of $[u_n'-u']\phi_\nu$ on each interval $[c_i,c_{i+1})$ on which $\phi_\nu$ is constant:
\begin{align}
\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}[u_n'(x) - u'(x)]\phi(x)\;dx &= \int_{c_i}^{c_i+1} \sin(2nx)\phi(x)\;dx\\
&=\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1} \sin(2nx)\phi_\nu(x)\;dx + \int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}\sin(2nx)(\phi(x) - \phi_\nu(x))\;dx \\
&=\phi_\nu(c_i)\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}\sin(2nx)\;dx+\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}\sin(2nx)(\phi(x) - \phi_\nu(x))\;dx \\
&= \phi_\nu(c_i)\frac{\cos(2nc_{i}) - \cos(2nc_{i+1})}{2n} +\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}\sin(2nx)(\phi(x) - \phi_\nu(x))\;dx 
\end{align}
Strong convergence of $\phi_\nu$ to $\phi$ means we can make the second integral arbitrarily close to zero. Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{c_i}^{c_i+1}[u_n'(x) - u'(x)]\phi(x)\;dx =0$$
So $u_n\rightharpoonup \sin(x)$ in $W^{1,2}$. Can you deal with strong convergence?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
First. About the weak convergence of $u'_n$, the integral is of $[u'_n-u]$ or $[u'_n-u']$? Because in the previous line you wrote $[u'_n-u']\phi_\nu$.
Second. Could you explain me why $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u'_n=\cos(x)$?
Third. Why you studied weak convergence both for $u$ and $u'$? I think because we are in a Sobolev space. Is it?

Comment: Ah it is $u_n' -u'$. That is a typo. I don't know where you got that limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n' = \cos(x)$ from. I don't see it in my answer. I looked at weak convergence in $L^2$ for $u_n$ and $u_n'$ because weak convergence in $W^{1,2}$ means that $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $L^2$ and $u_n'$ converges weakly to $u'$ in $L^2$.

Comment: More stuff. Can we study the strong convergence before and then use it to make some conclusion about the weak? If this is not possible, why? Thanks again, great answer.

Comment: You could do strong convergence first, since if $u_n$ converges strongly to $u$ in $L^2$, then of course $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$ in $L^2$. If you think strong convergence will be easier to prove, then that is all you have to show :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you calculate $u'_n$ and then you have calculated its limit for $n\rightarrow\infty$, but I realized that $u(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=\sin(x)$ and so $u'(x)=\cos(x)$. 
Usually we calculate the strong with the 2 integrals in the question, but they are hard to compute. So could you explain how to discuss the strong convergece? Or maybe give me just a hint. Thanks

Comment: I honestly do not think that $u_n'$ converges strongly to $u'$. Your job will be to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|u_n'-u'\|_{L^2}$ is a positive constant.

Comment: I've just confirmed that $u_n'$ does not converge strongly to $u'$. So $u_n$ cannot converge strongly in $W^{1,2}$. If you need additional guidance, just let me know!

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli I just noticed that you said the integrals are hard. But $u_n' - u' = \sin(2nx)$ so the squared $L^2$ norm is just $\int_0^1 \sin^2(2nx)\;dx$, which can easily be solved using trig identity $\sin^2(\theta) = \frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$.

Comment: Yeah sure that integral is not hard, so basically I use $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||u_n-u||=0$ to check the strong convergence and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int[u_n-u]\phi=0$ to check the weak convergence? Obviously if I have to check both convergences on $W^{1,2}$ I need to check them on $u(x)$ and $u'(x)$. Is it?

Comment: Yes, those are the definitions for strong and weak convergence. And yes, for convergence in $W^{1,2}$, $u_n,u_n'$ must converge to $u,u'$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Ok, you helped me a lot. If I'll have more stuff to ask, I'll write here. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry man, I've got another question for you. If I want to study the weak convergence and strong convergence but only in a $L^p$ space? I think that I have to prove the same equalities as before but only for $u$ and not for $u'$. It's right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Could you show the strong convergence of $u$ in this case? Or the calculus you make to say that it does not converge?

Comment: @jameswatt You should find that $||u_n' - u'|| = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sin(4n)}{8n}$. Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ yields a positive constant.

Comment: Why you take $u'$ and not $u$?

Comment: @jameswatt Were you not asking about strong convergence of $u_n$ in $W^{1,2}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry, but we need also the strong of $u$ or not?

Comment: @jameswatt If $u_n’$ does not converge strongly in $L^2$, then $u_n$ does not converge strongly in $W^{1,2}$. There is no need to check strong convergence of $u_n$ in $L^2$.